# Magento - Sort by Position and Name?

Tags: magento

Is it possible to sort by A the position and then B these products alphabetically shown.

I have new products and sale products coming into a category and they show all the new ones first then all the sale ones.

But I need to sort this by name.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**In admin**

Go to *Manage Categories*, select the category, then on it's products tab give each one a position number. They will be sorted according to that order.

**Programmatically**

You can do this by calling a product collection's `addAttributeToSort` method for each ordering.

For example, wherever you see in a template, `$_category->getProductCollection()` or `$_product->getCollection()` you can then add `->addAttributeToSort('position')->addAttributeToSort('name')` immediately after it.

`addAttributeToSort()` also takes a direction as a second parameter so you can have either `addAttributeToSort('name', 'asc')` or `addAttributeToSort('name', 'desc')`.

Comment: Can this be added within the list.phtml file or does it need to go in the list.php file in my locally copied core/mage/catalog/block/product/list.php? I've tried it in list.phtml at the top I added both position and name after <?php $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection() ?> so i got <?php $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSort('position')->addAttributeToSort('name') ?> Or is this in too late of a stage.

Comment: Have it working now to a degree Clockworkgeek but it always takes whatever the second attribute is, it seems to be applying them exclusively rather than together.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to go about it without changing any core files is to copy the Toolbar.php file located:

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php
```

then create a new directory path (if you haven't created one) under:

```
/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php
```

Now replace the following from line 232:

```
    if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
        $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
    }
```

to

```
if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
if(($this->getCurrentOrder())=='position'){ //defines the sort option
//sort by position (ascending) and entity_id (descending)
$this->_collection->addAttributeToSort('position','asc')->addAttributeToSort('entity_id','desc');
} else {
$this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(),$this->getCurrentDirection());
}
}
```

Lastly, reindex and refresh cache on your Magento backend and your ready to go. If you need to define more then one sort option copy and paste the code below just before *} else {*

```
if(($this->getCurrentOrder())=='######'){ //defines the sort option
//sort by ###### (ascending) and ###### (descending)
$this->_collection->addAttributeToSort('######','asc')->addAttributeToSort('######','desc');
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of coding, You can do it from the admin end .Login to your adminpanel
Goto *System--->Configuration* and choose *Catalog* from the left tab.

Then click the *Fronend* tab on the right. Goto *Product Lisiting Sort by* and choose *Name* from the dropdown and save the configuration.

To Make the sorting relatively easy. There is an extension available in the magento market. This extension will helps you to drag and drop the products to the position as per our wish. I provided the extension link below

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-sorting-sequence-drag-and-drop.html

Answer (score 0):

In response to clockworkgeek,

A product can have multiple attributes.  When you assign each product a single position, it relates to 1 attribute.  In addition, you would be required to decide a position for each product.

The problem here is that the dropdown on the product listings page offers you the opportunity to pick one of multiple attributes.  For example:

Size: S, M, L, XL

When you choose an attribute, the default is to sort that attribute alphabetical which does not make sense (L, M, S, XL).  Instead, I would like to use the same position of the attribute-option (s=1, m=2, l=3, xl=4) for sorting.

I am under the impression that doing this would be possible by performing a join and order by in Magento collections.  Do you know how to get those values or do sorting like that?